# How to get html of another website on the client-side?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I am trying to write a javascript script that would scrape the HTML source code of another website (ex. www.google.pl).
I found a few solutions, but none worked. I tried to run this code:

```
var url = "http://google.com/";
$.ajax({ 
url: url, 
success: function(data) { 
    alert(data); 
    } 
});
```

but it returns: "Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently (from disk cache)"

Do you have any code that would work?

Thank you :)

Comment: Maybe try -> `https`  But even then you might hit a CORS issue.

Comment: it doesnt help :(

Comment: You can't do it from the browser because of the Same Origin Policy. The 301 would be because they redirect to http to https

Comment: If you have no control over the domain then the cors will probably stop you. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: is it possible to bypass cors ?

Comment: For your own browser, yes with plugins. But for other people, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't.**

The [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) prevents cross-origin reads.

You can only perform read operations on your own domain.

For example: a script at `https://foo.com/some-script.js/` can typically request a resource from `https://foo.com/about-us`, but not `https://bar.com/about-us/`.

If you think about it, this restriction is critical for keeping the web safe. For example, you wouldn't want any arbitrary site to be capable of accessing your bank account, would you?

If the owners of a website *want* to make a certain resource available to other domains, they can enable cross-origin resource sharing (see Mozilla's article on [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) for more information), but this is up to them.